# How does stoi() function work with stringstream in C++?

Tags: c++, stoi

So I'm new to C++, so bear with me here. I'm trying to read a csv file and parsing the data into smaller strings to hold in my class. As I attempt t do this, I come across a problem with stoi(). Every time I try to convert my string to an int, I get an error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  stoi".

I have tried checking to see if my string is an actual number and it is. I have checked if there is a space or any other weird character, there isn't. I'm not sure what's wrong. Guidance will be appreciated.

Edit: Here is my code

```
class MusicData 
{
  public:
  void setDate(string theDate) {date = theDate;}
  void setRank(int theRank) {rank = theRank;}
  void setSongName(string theSong) {song = theSong;}
  void setArtist(string theArtist) {artist = theArtist;}
  void setLastWeek(int theLastWeek) {lastWeek = theLastWeek;}
  void setPeakRank(int thePeakRank) {peakRank = thePeakRank;}
  void setTotalWeeks(int total) {weeksOnBoard = total;}
  string getDate()  {return date;}
  int getRank() {return rank;}
  string getSong() {return song;}
  string getArtist() {return artist;}
  int getLastWeek() {return lastWeek;}
  int getPeakRank() {return peakRank;}
  int getTotalWeeks() {return weeksOnBoard;}

 private:
 int rank, lastWeek, peakRank, weeksOnBoard;
 string date, song, artist;
};


void readFromFile( const char fileName[], vector <string>& hold )   
{
  MusicData aSong;
  ifstream file;
  file.open(fileName);    
       
  assert(file.fail() == false);    
  string data;
  string date, str_ranks, songName, artist, str_last_week;
  int ranks, lastWeek;
  while (getline(file, data))
  {
    stringstream s(data);

    getline(s, date, ',');
    aSong.setDate(date);

    getline(s, str_ranks, ',');
    ranks = stoi(str_ranks);
  }

  file.close();
}
```

Comment: Add your code here?

Comment: Please create a [mre]. With the information given, it's just guessing at the problem.

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/

Comment: With a `stringstream` you may be able to use `>>` and avoid `stoi` completely.

Comment: I've tried that. For some reason, it doesn't print out the right song title after I use stringstream. I'm really confused as it is my first time using stringstream. I've used stoi(), but I'm unsure why this doesn't work.

Comment: `stoi` throws an exception of that type if provided string can't be converted you have to handle that by using try\catch block.  And this requires debugging info (input, output examples as well) to understand why you are getting wrong input.

Comment: Please show a [mre] including your input file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator>>` will read a stream directly into an integer (you don't need to manually convert it).

```
  string data;
  int rank;
  while (getline(file, data))
  {
      stringstream s(data);

      // Always check stream operations worked.
      if (getline(s, date, ',')) {
          aSong.setDate(date);     // Why is Date a string.
                                   // Should this not be its own type?

          char sep = 'X';
          if (s >> rank >> sep && sep == ',') {
              aSong.setRank(rank)
          }
      }
  }
```

Though I would write `operator>>` for the `MusicData` class so that it can read its own data from the stream.

```
  class MusicData
  {
        // STUFF
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, MusicData& value);
  };
```